# What would happen if a system executes a part of the file that is zero-padded?

Tags: file, assembly, machine-code, zero-padding

I've seen in some posts/videos/files that they are zero-padded to look bigger than they are, or match "same file size" criteria some file system utilities have for moving files, mostly they are either prank programs, or malware.

But I often wondered, what would happen if the file corrupted, and would "load" the next set of "instructions" that are in the big zero-padded space at the end of the file?

Would anything happen? What's the instruction set for `0x0`?

Comment: That depends on what architecture the program has been written for.

Comment: On x86-64 `00 00` is `add [rax],al` (`add [eax],al` in 32b mode). On Z80 `00` is `nop`, etc... (each CPU may have different instruction set and opcodes).

Comment: executable files are often padded with NOPs, [which are not zeros in x86](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25545470/995714). And in debug mode it may be padded with [other values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Comment: @prl: The OP is talking about that posts and videos they've seen which said that "fake" executable files are sometimes padded.

Comment: One video even got as far as to open one of those files in a hex editor and show the masses of 0's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The decoding of `0` bytes completely depends on the CPU architecture.  On many architectures, instruction are fixed length (for example 32-bit), so the relevant thing would be `00 00 00 00` (using hexdump notation).

On most Linux distros, clang/llvm comes with support for multiple target architectures built-in (`clang -target` and `llvm-objdump`), unlike gcc / gas / binutils, so I was able to use that to check for some architectures I didn't have cross-gcc / binutils installed for.  Use `llvm-objdump --version` to see the supported list.  (But I didn't figure out how to get it to disassemble a raw binary like binutils `objdump -b binary`, and my clang won't create SPARC binaries on its own.)

---

On x86, `00 00` (2 bytes) decodes (http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html) as an [8-bit `add` with a memory destination](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/ADD.html).  The first byte is the opcode, the 2nd byte is the ModR/M that specifies the operands.

This usually segfaults right away (if `eax/rax` isn't a valid pointer), or segfaults once execution falls off the end of the zero-padded part into an unmapped page.  (**This happens in real life because of bugs like [falling off the end of `_start`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014568/assembly-segmentation-fault-after-making-a-system-call-at-the-end-of-my-code) without making an exit system call**), although in those cases the following bytes aren't always all zero.  e.g. data, or ELF metadata.)

---

**x86 64-bit mode**: `ndisasm -b64 /dev/zero | head`:

```
address   machine code      disassembly
00000000  0000              add [rax],al
```

x86 32-bit mode (`-b32`):

```
00000000  0000              add [eax],al
```

x86 16-bit mode:  (`-b16`):

```
00000000  0000              add [bx+si],al
```

---

**AArch32 ARM mode**: `cd /tmp` && `dd if=/dev/zero of=zero bs=16 count=1` && `arm-none-eabi-objdump  -z -D -b binary -marm zero`.  (Without `-z`, objdump skips over large blocks of all-zero and shows `...`)

```
addr   machine code   disassembly
0:   00000000        andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

**ARM Thumb/Thumb2**: `arm-none-eabi-objdump  -z -D -b binary -marm --disassembler-options=force-thumb zero`

```
0:   0000            movs    r0, r0
2:   0000            movs    r0, r0
```

**AArch64**: `aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -z -D -b binary -maarch64  zero`

```
 0:   00000000        .inst   0x00000000 ; undefined
```

---

**MIPS32**: `echo .long 0 > zero.S` && `clang -c -target mips zero.S` && `llvm-objdump -d zero.o`

```
zero.o: file format ELF32-mips
Disassembly of section .text:
   0:       00 00 00 00     nop
```

**PowerPC 32 and 64-bit**: `-target powerpc` and `-target powerpc64`.  IDK if any extensions to PowerPC use the `00 00 00 00` instruction encoding for anything, or if it's still an illegal instruction on modern IBM POWER chips.

```
zero.o: file format ELF32-ppc   (or ELF64-ppc64)
Disassembly of section .text:
   0:       00 00 00 00  <unknown>
```

**IBM S390**: `clang -c -target systemz zero.S`

```
zero.o: file format ELF64-s390
Disassembly of section .text:
   0:       00 00  <unknown>
   2:       00 00  <unknown>
```