# Long consecutive number of "add" opcodes after disassembling

Tags: disassembly, portable-executable, malware, opcode, radare2

After disassembling PE 32 files using radare2 to extract opcodes from, I noticed that near the beginning of the opcodes I get a long consecutive list of "add" opcodes. I am wondering if anyone knows the reason for that and why it is there.

Comment: Look at the encoding. It's probably just a bunch of zeroes.

Comment: Ah thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would happen if a system executes a part of the file that is zero-padded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150909/what-would-happen-if-a-system-executes-a-part-of-the-file-that-is-zero-padded)